# DocuSign: Changing the Sender through DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

I just wanna know if there's a way to change the sender of the envelopes so the user who sends it will have the privilege to void the envelope. For now it is sending through one account only, and it is the only account who can void it. We want the each one who send it to be able to void the envelope.

We tried Send On Behalf Of (SOBO), but its not working, do you have any suggestions?

This is a DocuSign-Dynamics CRM integration.We want the user who send the envelope to have the power to void and not only the service account that's configured for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With DocuSign you can have multiple users in a given account with various permissions for the users - ie Admin, Sender, Viewer, or some other custom profile.

When you send a DocuSign envelope from a given account, the sender has the ability to void the envelope as does Admin users in that account.